# Email format not supported in MS Outlook 2007

Tags: asp.net, outlook, outlook-2007, inline-code

I am creating the email format from my code-behind. In that I am using the `<div>` tags and also the `<a>` tags. and for them i am applying the style `background:url` property. Using this way I am getting the emails with images and style. It works proper in the Thunderbird but not in MS Outlook 2007. It prevents the inline images form render.

Is there any other way that I can insert the images inline.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most email clients like Outlook does not render divs properly try to do as following

1. Do not use Divs.
2. Only use tables and use fixed width in pixels on each table cell
   etc.
3. Only use inline styling.
4. Make sure your images are accessible. like
   www.mywebsite.com/image1.gif so that outlook can download it.

There are more but these are the basic things which needs to be addressed.

Comment: I found that you need to avoid background images also as these do not render.

Comment: I am not sure about background images as i have not tested it. but i personally uses embedded resources for the images in asp.net.

Comment: @KamranPervaiz: You have to use **<img/>** to set backgrounds

Comment: thanks all ,I used the Image control to the images inside the Email,and also the Table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `div`. Since Email templates doesn't support div, you have to use `table` instead. 
Instead of `background` use `image`, but with `border` which set to 0.

```
<img src="yourimage" alt="My Image" />
```

-->>see [HTML Images](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

You might have a look at this article about [Email Templates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14367/Email-Templates)